# preg match multiline text ends with a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, multiline

i have some html text with regular text in as well, i need to to be removed.

Example on text would be

```
<h3>title</h3>
this is some text
This some more

This more more, Continue reading.
```

I tried a million combinations, i just dont get the preg stuff, im using regex101 site to test every one, noone works of all my testing.

Tried like this (and million other combinations i feel)

```
<h3>.*?<\/h3>.*?{$\'Continue reading.\'}
```

I simply dont get the wierd buildup of preg, i mean i get i need start from `<h3>` and end at first string of "Continue reading." after the `<h3>`, but how to match this up over multiple lines is beyond me.

Can someone do and example and explain why? i read about multiline ect, but nothing works for me, i dont see it..

Thanks

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Use the `s` modifier for multi line matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the entire string (or any string, in reality) you can use `preg_replace` and set the second parameter to `""`; additionally you need to use the `s` modifier/flag to make the `.` selector match new lines (or use some other selector that matches *anything*).

**Regex**

```
/<h3>.*?Continue reading\./s
/                            : Starting delimiter
 <h3>                        : Matches a literal <h3>
     .*?                     : Non-greedy match any character 0 or more times
        Continue reading     : Matches literally the text "Continue reading"
                        \.   : Match a literal period/full-stop
                          /  : Ending delimiter
                           s : Modifier/flag to make `.` match new lines
```

**Code Example**

In this example we've used `"Erased"` instead of `""`, to make it clear what's happened:

```
$string = "<h3>title</h3>
this is some text
This some more

This more more, Continue reading.";

$string = preg_replace('/<h3>.*?Continue reading\./s', "Erased", $string);

echo $string; // Output: Erased
```

Use `""` instead of `"Erased"` to completely remove the text:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<h3>.*?Continue reading\./s', "", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks man, i think the problem was (among others) i forgot the \ at the ., just did a test and it works like a charm, i was in doubt if i had to ($text) or \"text\" or something, and it was hard to find any information on.

Again thanks :)

Comment: @BoBjering no worries. If you mean you weren't sure how to put the literal strings in then (as hopefully you can see in the answer) you just type them in and escape any "special" characters (such as: `[]{}()\".?=*`) as needed. Some characters have a specific purpose if a `\ ` is placed before it for example: `\w` means any letter, number or under score and can also be written as a character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` << a character class is equal to one character only; so, for example, if you wanted to match upper & lowercase `C` at the start of `Continue reading` you'd use `[cC]ontinue reading`